# Доступ к свойству объекта через адрес этого объекта

Tags: c++

```
Class1 object;
int x = &object.x;
```

Возможно ли такое?
Получит ли переменная x значение свойства x объекта object?
Не получается ли тут так, что запрашивается свойство адреса? (что бессмысленно).

Comment: Доброго времени суток! 
1) Ваш пример вызовет ошибку времени компиляции, если переменная object.x является приватным полем класса.

2) Если object.x является открытым полем класса, то теоретически код может скомпилироваться, но с предупреждением. Дело в том, что конструкция &object.x трактуется как получение **адреса** переменной (т.е. указателя на нее). Но, так как указатель является числом, то присваивание в целом возможно.

3) Свойства (как в C# или Java) **стандартом C++ не проддерживаются** а поддерживаются только некоторыми компиляторами как нестандартные расширения.

Answer (score 6):

Ваш код не очень корректен. И вот почему.

```
int x = &object.x
```

это не значение, хранящееся в x, а его адрес, следовательно вы получите примерно такую ошибку:

> invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'

Но это не все. Согласно стандарту  размер указателя не является фиксированным, а зависит от конкретной реализации. Размер int тоже не фиксирован, и тоже зависит от реализации.  Поэтому если вы будете кастовать int* к int, далеко не факт, что первый уместится во втором, а потому весьма вероятно, что вы получите ошибку компиляции